# My react app does not appear the screen is white

Tags: reactjs

My react app doesn't appear the screen is all white and it gives me no error just this warning --> [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:7784) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (probably not the best one)  https://github.com/DrVipinKumar/ReactAllProjects/blob/main/reactwithspring/public/MiddlewareDeprecationSolution.txt
And same solution on Youtube
https://youtu.be/ifSTp9WEHpo